# Modify XML Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

So, I have an XML file that needs to be sent to a server via the POST request. Everything works, however, here is an issue. This XML file has a transaction ID that needs to be incremented every time when it's being sent to a server. When I create multiple threads(requests) and send them over to the server, only one request gets processed, and everything else gets declined because they all have the same transaction ID. I was wondering if there is a way to increment a transaction ID inside the XML file with every generated thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function call where you have currently the transaction id:

> ${__counter(FALSE)}

Comment: Happy to help, thanks for feedback, validation and upvote !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're sending the file.

1. If you're doing it via Body Data tab of the HTTP Request sampler using [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function just replace the transaction ID with [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function in the file itself and wrap everything into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.xml,,)})}
   ```

   more information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)
2. If you're sending the file via "Files upload" tab the only way is to read the file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), change the value and write it back in the runtime, see [Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) article for more details.